# Better way to pass vector of LargeData

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Need to design a function to return an array of BigClass. In order to prevent unnecessary copy, there are two options for me.

```
struct BigClass
{
    int manyfields;    
};

boost::shared_ptr<vector<BigClass> > Fun1()
{
    throw;
}

vector<boost::shared_ptr<BigClass> > Fun2()
{
    throw;
}
```

Question> Which method is a better choice? If none of above is good, please provide a better one.

Thank you

Comment: Is returning a reference not an option? (`std::vector<BigClass>& func(void);`) :v

Comment: No. I do NOT allow to return a reference b/c I don't want to store anything internally. In the real code, the function FunX is a member function and I don't want to use a member variable to hold the array of BigClass. Instead, each time the FuncX will recreate the array of BigClass. The user of FunX will make limited call and each time the user will provide new input data and FunX will have to recompute.

Comment: can you use c++11 move semantics?

Comment: No C++11 syntax yet. We are only allowed to use VS2010.

Comment: VS2010 has move semantics AFAIK

Comment: The copy could be elided anyway. No way to know for sure without having some visible side-effects in the copy constructor of `BigClass` to test and see what's going on. (Like printing a message to the console)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without return value optimizations, `boost::shared_ptr<vector<BigClass> >` has less overhead than `vector<boost::shared_ptr<BigClass> >`.  The first makes a copy of one pointer, the second copies N shared pointers inside of vector.

Also, the second form has less cache/memory coherency.  Each BigClass is allocated separately on the heap, where as in the first form, all the `BigClass` are in one continuous block.

Comment: That big contiguous block can be a problem.  Allocating large amounts of space can be difficult if memory gets fragmented.  If `BigClass` is sufficiently large, it may be easier (memory-wise) to have a vector of shared pointers instead of a shared pointer to a vector.  You would have to profile your application to determine which would be better.

Comment: Also, copying a shared pointer involves copying the at least the pointer, often a second one (for weakrefs) and atomically incrementing the reference count. For the rest: good observation.

Answer (score 3):

VS2010 allows you to use move semantics.

This means that:
`std::vector<BigClass> retBigVector() { return std::vector<BigClass>(); }` will work just fine.
retBigVector will construct a big vector and move it into wherever you wish.

This is one of the major reasons why move semantics have emerged - and again, VS2010 supports this.

Comment: Nice to see you back in business, +1

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr > would require less memory, especially for large vectors; vector > is more flexible as it allows memory-conscious vector manipulations, such as adding/removing elements or sorting.

If you vector is of manageable size I would go with Fun2. If your vectors are huge AND you are confident that the returned vectors will be used for read only go with Fun1.

Answer (score 0):

Try boost::vector_ptr:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html

You can then get the pointer by the usual [] operator. Many other ptr_containers are available.